# make div clickable with jquery

Tags: jquery

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FgZnK/1/

Clicking on the box goes to a page not found. How can I make this work?

**HTML**

```
<div class="myBox"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location=$(this).attr("http://google.com");
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the correct code:

```
$(".myBox").click(function() {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
});
```

Answer (score 6):

http://jsfiddle.net/FgZnK/2/

HTML

```
<div class="myBox" data-href="http://google.com/">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("data-href");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In this chunk here:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
window.location=$(this).attr("http://google.com");
 return false;
});
```

You're actually trying to read the non-existent attribute *named* `http://google.com`.

Instead, just use:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location = 'http://google.com';
});
```

If instead you want the actual destination to be in the mark up rather than the script, use:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

and put an `href` attribute on your DIV, just like you would on an A link.

There's no need for `return false` in any of these handlers because a DIV doesn't have a default action that needs preventing, unlike a normal link.

Comment: why return false after window.location?

Answer (score 1):

Open in new window....

```
    $("#whatever").click(function() {
        window.open(
          'https://www.example.com',
          '_blank' // open in new window
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location="http://google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location.href="http://google.com";
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the faulty line :

```
window.location=$(this).attr("http://google.com");
```

This doesn't make any sense, you're trying to change the location to the value of the attribute named "http://google.com" of your div.

Just correct it like this :

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location= "http://google.com";
     return false;
});
```